# Can anyone identify what Sci-Fi movie this character was in?

Tags: movie, character-identification

I need help to identify the movie this character was in.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's meant to be a character from a movie, or is it just  mishmash of different scifi-ish elements?

Comment: I see that you originally titled your question "Can anyone ID what Syfy movie this was in?", but that it's been edited. Did you actually mean that you know it's from a movie aired on the TV channel called Syfy (previously called Sci-Fi Channel)?

Comment: Have you contacted the store to ask?

Comment: what's written on the piece of card/paper at the bottom?

Comment: @AidanO - "Super Sale!". You can click the image for bigger version

Comment: @Gallifreyan thanks, hoped it might be something more helpful...

Comment: Or, carefully lift the thing and look for inscriptions on the bottom of the pedestal.

Comment: He looks familiar (style and studio), and if you would be willing to give me some additional photographs I can search around.  **A)** the mark on his head.  **B)** the emblem on his gun — it resembles a ram or some other face with horns.  **C)** the pupils of his eyes.

Comment: @can-ned_food I feel like I've seen this guy, in some post-apocalyptic film maybe. The goggles and the gun seem familiar

Comment: At least tell us the location of the thrift shop where you saw this!

Comment: I don't think this asker|querent cares, but I downvoted an otherwise intriguing question due to lack of information.

Comment: He looks like one of the guys from "The men in black" series

Comment: @Manognyayella If you think you can answer, then post an answer please.  However, I don't remember ever seeing this guy in any MiB movie or cartoon episode which I've seen.  Was he in the books?

Comment: I'm wondering if the peice of paper behind is related. I can see "SEASON" and possibly "APC" at the top. That might match his tatoo...?

Comment: @n00dles - I suspect the sign is unrelated. APO(logies), presumably.