# Can you identify this Indiana Jones-like hero?

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Can you identify this hero? This photo was used in a games magazine "Top Secret #2" published in December 1990.

Here's the whole page:

[image]

On the top they used a photo from the *Full Metal Jacket* movie so it seems they just used random photos to illustrate games.

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect this is a character from science fiction and fantasy rather than a generic action/adventure hero?

Comment: Kinda looks like [Garth](https://indianajones.fandom.com/wiki/Garth), but I don't remember coming out of the bushes like that....

Comment: The text "Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade" immediately above it suggests to me that this might actually *be* Indiana Jones (or as close as the magazine-writers could legally get to his likeness).

Comment: @F1Krazy In 1990 in Poland nobody cared about copyrights

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It resembles Indiana Jones and Indiana Jones is sci-fi/fantasy series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4JDV3AVkSI)

Comment: I agree that it looks like someone wanted a picture of Indiana Jones and found this similar image instead, and for reasons unknown, they ran with it. Perhaps the person who found images didn’t know what Harrison Ford looks like. Perhaps they did worry about copyright. In 1990 they would have had to locate a physical photo - there was no google image search and the images found by Archie or Veronica would not have been camera ready by a long shot.

Comment: I don't agree with this closing. Indiana Jones is firmly on topic and the picture is clearly intended to be related to the film (next to the Indiana Jones game in the magazine).

Comment: I wonder if this was a production image from [The Mines of Kilimanjaro](https://monsterhuntermoviereviews.com/2015/03/25/the-mines-of-kilimanjaro-1986/).

Comment: @DigitalJedi - I don't think it is. The hat (and actor) are different

Comment: @Valorum Right, I meant to mention that I noticed they used different hats in the production art. But it could just be rando actor. It sorta has that standard video game box art look.

Comment: @DigitalJedi - I don't know why, but I get the feeling that this picture is cropped from a box-art rather than being a still from a film

Comment: @Valorum This is quite possible. I doubt they had access to anything exclusive/limited, like a production image.

Comment: It could be a picture of a staff member behind a potted plant in the lobby for all we know. Google Lens was useless.

Comment: It makes me think of https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=robbers+of+the+sacred+mountain&sxsrf=ALeKk00tedbe7o5rtheqr7FlJ7haihbHWg%3A1622390264327&source=hp&ei=-LWzYLbZEYG4lwSbhpK4BA&gs_ssp=eJzj4tZP1zc0MqhKzk3ONmD0kivKT0pKLSpWyE9TKMlIVShOTC5KTVHIzS_NK0nMzAMATNIPgQ&oq=robbers+of+&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBABGAEyAggAMgIILjICCAAyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoFCAAQsQM6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOggILhCxAxCDAToOCC4QsQMQxwEQowIQkwI6BQguELEDOggILhCxAxCTAjoICC4QxwEQrwFQkRRYnTlgpEFoAXAAeACAAdsBiAHFCpIBBTQuNi4xmAEAoAEBsAEA&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp#imgrc=3yCtdCIzN_JmlM

Comment: For some strange reasons, part of the tip of the hat, right above the eye, makes me feel like the hat was edited in.

Comment: Now I'm very curious as to whether or not it's possible for the entirety of the left side of his face to be illuminated if he's wearing a hat, unless the sun is below him (I mean, there isn't a single trace of hat shadow on the illuminated side. Maybe with some artificial lightings? Hmm...

Comment: I'm combing through old ads and stock photos for "Pitfall" which fit the aesthetic but no match

Comment: @Clockwork I think the hat is composited in.  Yes, this was a thing before Photoshop -- it was just done in darkroom or with an airbrush.  See the little line of light just below the brim near the bridge of the nose?

Comment: Reuploaded page from that magazine: https://ibb.co/1qLB8cX

Comment: I think it's Richard Young (Fedora), aka "Garth" as Skooba commented - the character in "Last Crusade" on which young Indiana Jones chose to style himself.

Comment: The plant is definitely bamboo. You can see vertical canes to the left of the hat-wearer. Also, the Polish text is all game cheat codes.

Comment: I've emailed the magazine's editor. He's having a look through his records. Hopefully he can shed some light :-)

Comment: @Valorum There are also graphic artists and a lead graphic designer listed in the masthead.

Comment: @Spencer - I think I'll try them next

Comment: @Valorum I think this is a lost cause :(

Comment: @Tom - Which will make it all the sweeter when we find it.

Comment: A bit late to the discussion, but for the time it's possible this was a publicity shot for Rick Dangerous (released in '89, just before this magazine was made in '90)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Dangerous

Comment: @amkingTRP I looked for photos from Rick Dangerous and nothing looks like this

Comment: Dang, I was hoping we'd have had some update since.

Comment: @Clockwork Identifying this photo seems harder than I thought