# Need help identifying this character

Tags: movie, character-identification

Found this head at a yard sale. It's 3 inches high.[image]

Comment: Did you buy it? And if so, what does it look like from the top/side/rear/underside?

Comment: Hmm... It reminds me of the cartoon art of Jean Giraud (Moebius).

Comment: Can you provide any other angles or details? Any details on the bottom, like an artist signature or date? What material is it made of?

Comment: Wjat makes you think it has anything to do with science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @Valorum I was about to vote to close this question because of its apparent lack of fantastical elements, but you had to go and put a bounty on it. Why?

Comment: @user14111 - It looks like a fantasy character to me

Comment: It also looks Russian from here, not sure what the chances of identifying it are. @user14111

Comment: That is clearly the superhero Jade-head, he used to be really into the job, but doesn't quite care any more...

Comment: I saw a French saint bust once that closely resembles the picture - but I can't think of his name!