# Please help me identify this man with something on the forehead. He's on a homemade button badge

Tags: character-identification

[image: Head of unknown character]

Drawing of unknown character - please help to identify him.

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried putting the image through Google Image to see what comes up. It says the button badge depicts an owl.

Comment: @Clockwork - It found me some nice pictures of rulers...

Answer (score 56):

[Adam Warlock](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Adam_Warlock_(Earth-616)), a Marvel Comics character created by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby in [Fantastic Four #66](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_66) (June, 1967). Probably drawn by [Jim Starlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Starlin) in your image. Starlin redefined the character in his own series Warlock (1970s) and made use of him as one of the main characters in his Infinity Saga series during the 90s. Thanos, created by Starlin, and who you may know from MCU, is considered his arch-villain. As @MartianInvader commented, you can find the MCU version of Warlock in Guardians of the Galaxy vol.3

[image: Adam Warlock]

To be more precise, your badge's image is taken from [*Strange Tales #180*](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_180)

[image: Strange Tales 181 cover]

[image: Original panel]

Image in context

[image: Splash page]

By the way, apart from using internet, I used "old-school" techniques. Meaning "having a physical copy of those comics". Below you can see the big gallery edition recently published in Spain. :-)

[image: Spanish Gallery Edition]

Comment: You mention Thanos is in the MCU, but Adam Warlock is too! Not nearly as prominently, of course, but he plays a reasonably important role in Guardians of the Galaxy 3.