# In the Marvel Multiverse, Are Yahweh, God and the One-Above-All the same being?

Tags: marvel, religion

In the Marvel Multiverse, there are at least three supreme beings who seem to represent an all-powerful, monotheistic God,

- Yahweh:

[image: Yahweh]

- God:

[image: God]

- The One-Above-All:

[image: The One-Above-All]

Are these characters meant to be the same being? If not, has there been any explanations for their mutual existence?

Comment: Clearly not; God is [Jack Kirby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Kirby), while The One-Above-All is obviously [Julian Richings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Richings)

Comment: @JasonBaker Have you ever seen Kirby and Richings in the same room together?

Comment: That picture of Yahweh is from Marville, right? Where God goes by the name of Jack, convinces the characters to go skinny dipping with him, explains that we should feel sad about killing microscopic bacteria, and reveals that all humans are descended from Wolverine? I sure hope that version of God is completely unrelated to any other depiction. Ugh, now I have to forget that comic exists...

Comment: @Thunderforge I don't think so. It's from the Yahweh (616) Marvel Wiki page. Besides, wasn't the Marville version young and black?

Comment: @RogueJedi He was for most of Marville, yes, but I thought he briefly appeared as old, white, and bearded in that issue. Also, the art style, the lack of dialogue balloons seen in the upper left corner (dialogue was bizarrely just printed straight on the page in that issue), and a reference to Lucinda (one of the characters was named Lucy) make me pretty sure it's from Marville #3.

Comment: What's "Marville?"

Comment: @T-1000'sSon One of the [15 Worst Comics of the 2000s](http://comicsalliance.com/the-15-worst-comics-of-the-decade/). Also, that link shows that the first image is from Marville.

Comment: @Thunderforge I'll try to find a new image. Thanks for the info.

Comment: See Thaddeus Howze's answers [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55337/are-there-any-actual-gods-in-marvel-comics), [here](https://www.quora.com/Who-is-the-most-powerful-being-in-the-Marvel-franchise) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-god-being-Yahweh-depicted-in-the-Ghost-Rider-series-the-same-entity-as-Marvels-The-One-Above-All/answer/Thaddeus-Howze). Last one probably applies most to your question.

Comment: I don't get it. In the first comic you posted, the God character wants to trademark the name "God", and the term "Yahweh" does not seem to appear at all. Are you sure that's Yahweh? If so, looks like Yahweh is just another name for God.

Comment: @user14111 "If so, looks like Yahweh is just another name for God."  Well yeah, and that was true long long before Marvel.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that the One Above All is whatever god (if any) the reader believes is the real God - allowing the reader to justify reading stories set in a universe that has, among others, the Norse and Greco-Roman pantheons as characters. This, however is a meta-explanation, and I’ve never read an interview or article that clearly states this.

Answer (score 5):

No. The One-Above-All is the supreme God of the marvel multiverse. Yahweh is a Skyfather in the same vein as Odin or Zeus.

Yahweh even states this himself when he spoke to Howard the Duck. He said that he is NOT the one who created the universe but rather is it's "suppiler" (read [Howard the Duck Vol 3 #6](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Howard_the_Duck_Vol_3_6) for that) and even says he's not the only god in the marvel universe making reference to the Norse, Greek and Egyptian pantheons.

Unlike the only person in this thread my answer is backed by the comics canon. I can't find a single source that says the One-Above-All created Angels or even Heaven. The One-Above-All's domain is called the "House of Ideas" not Heaven. There are also multiple Yahweh's in the marvel multiverse while the One-Above-All has no copies in any other universe. The Yahweh Howard the Duck spoke to was the main marvel canon (Earth 616) Yahweh but the 2099 universe (Earth 928) also has a Yahweh who was allegedly killed by Thanatos.

And if all this wasn't even to convince you then go to the marvel wiki you'll see that the One-Above-All and Yahweh have separate pages. If they were the same being wouldn't they be in one page?

So no they are not the same being. The One-Above-All is CLEARLY a separate entity.

Comment: This is good material, but you've ignored God; how does he (?) relate to the others?  Also you could make this better by providing references for Yahweh being dead in the Earth 928 universe and the "House of Ideas."

Answer (score -1):

They are the same. Yahweh is like an avatar of One Above All. One Above All created Heaven and angels and his principal home is Heaven so they are the same entity. One above all can to be what He wants and one of his face is like Yahweh

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this, comic panels, quotes, etc, that you could [edit] in to back this up?